# ClassCastException while retrieving datasource from InitialContext

Tags: java, classcastexception, weblogic12c

I'm getting the following error while attempting to retrieve a datasource object from my initial context using Oracle WebLogic 12.1:

> "Problem creating dummy orb: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid:SUN minor code:203 completed: NO" and "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object can not cast to java.io.Serializable"

The code is:

```
Hashtable h=new Hashtable();

h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001/");
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"ck");
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"monster26");

Context c = new InitialContext(h);

DataSource ds = (DataSource) c.lookup("lic.mod.mypool");
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

All help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem

I solved it changing the web logic client

Im using now this version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```